# How do I get the user avatar picture?

Tags: theming

I am working on a custom Drupal 8 theme and I am trying to get the user avatar picture on a variable and output somewhere in the HTML.

I have created this function to get the name & email of the current user logged in like so:

```
#Function to get the user name value & output in the HTML DOM
function tropical_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  # gets current user name
  $user_logged_in_name = $variables['user']->getDisplayName();

  # creates value to ouput in the DOM & capitalize first letter
  $variables['user_logged_in_name'] = ucfirst($user_logged_in_name);

  # gets user email
  $user_email = $variables['user']->getEmail();
  $variables['user_email'] = $user_email;
}
```

That worked perfectly! Now I am trying to get the user profile picture, but I am not able to do it. Any help will be appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get Url it by   `get('user_picture')->entity->url()`( you can get URI too with `get('user_picture')->entity->getFileUri()`), So

```
function tropical_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  // gets current user name
  $user_logged_in_name = $variables['user']->getDisplayName();

  // creates value to ouput in the DOM & capitalize first letter
  $variables['user_logged_in_name'] = ucfirst($user_logged_in_name);

  // gets user email
  $user_email = $variables['user']->getEmail();
  $variables['user_email'] = $user_email;

  // get user picture
  $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id())
  $variables['user_picture'] = $user->get('user_picture')->entity->url();

}
```

Additionally,  If you want to get the default image when the user account doesn't have an image associated, use the following code.

```
$field = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', 'user_picture');
$default_image = $field->getSetting('default_image');
$file = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
$picture = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
```

Comment: @ManuelAbascal you're very welcome. :)